# Accessing the OneDrive for Business of several enterprises via a single application?

Tags: azure, sharepoint, office365, onedrive

The application I'm working on allow users to import files from Google Drive and OneDrive. I would like to support OneDrive for Business but I'm not sure if this is possible.

From what I read, in order to use the OneDrive for Business API one needs to create an Azure application linked to a specific AD. Does that mean a third party application can only access the OneDrive of the users within the AD it was registered in? Would I have to create a different Azure application for each "enterprise"?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely create an app that users from multiple tenants can access. Here's a [blog post explaining the differences between single and multi-tenant](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/azure-ad-what%E2%80%99s-the-difference-between-single-vs-multi-tenant). You can also check out this [code sample](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-MultiTenant-OpenIdConnect-DotNet) from Azure that demonstrates and walks you through a similar scenario.